# Positioning element to the left bottom corner without covering anything

Tags: html, css, css-position

I got two elements in a parent block and i want one in the top left corner, and the second one in the bottom right corner, i also need them not to overlay each other.

I tried:

- `absolute` positioning: they overlay
- `flexbox`: when the space is too small and the second element is created a new row, it floats to the left

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not overlaying each other"? - Maybe you can also in czech, probably would be easier for explanation (můžeš i česky, bude asi snažší na vysvětlení)

Comment: Aby se nepřekrývaly, mám cenu a přidat do košíku, což se při absolutním pozicování při nedostatku místa zobrazí přes cenu.

Comment: Can you send link, i'll check it out in a while. (Můžeš poslat link, za chvilku bych se na to podíval)

Comment: for example [here](http://zahrada-online.cz/product/34) but the html structure a little bit different now.

Comment: This should help (tohle by mělo pomoct) - there is no simple way to code relatively for bottom right position without overlaying.
`@media(max-width:1000px){
    input#product_addtocart {
         position: relative;
         float:right;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

When the overlapping is about to happen, you will have to add conditional styling and change the positioning of the right absolute element to relative

```
@media(max-width:1000px){ input#product_addtocart { position: relative; float:right; } }
```

When the viewport width is below 1000px (elements are about to overlap each other) - just change the positioning to relative, to avoid that.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3t2rgc8/

Comment: It is quite sad that css can't accomplish such a common task. This solution will work with normal people just fine, but it counts with a fixed width of both elements. if i were to put too many numbers in the price tag, the add to cart button does not care and is displayed over said price. Maybe i can accomplish this with javascript.

Comment: Well you could float, or make the two elements act as an "inline-block", but then you would have to solve the vertical alignment probably again with conditional styling... But hey, don't be sad about it - the conditional styling is quite common practice widely used. We could get a new web standards in future solving such cases elegantly, but that is uncertain. Anyway - Happy coding and Hodně štěstí ;)